# How do I add lit-html to an existing project?

Tags: javascript, lit-html

I understand I can import `lit-html` using a `<script type="module">` tag in say `index.html`, but I can't access `html` or `render` from a separate JS script (e.g. `index.js`). Is this currently possible?

Comment: Please explain what you mean `can't access`?

Comment: @Justinas Check this fiddle, I get an error when I attempt to use `html` in a different script https://jsfiddle.net/mike_seekwell/rzhofu81/265/

Comment: Using ES Modules has different scopes from typical scripts. If you want to use `html` in multiple places, you have to import it in each of those locations.

Comment: Thanks @abraham, but how would I import into an existing plain vanilla JS script (e.g. `index.js`)?

Comment: `lit-html` only has an ES Module build available. If you want to use it in a non-module context you'll have to process it with something like Rollup, Babel, or Webpack.

Comment: we use 
npm i lit

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering an old question, but the docs may have been updated since 2018. Now they provide instructions on how to do this.

[Install lit-html with npm](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/getting-started#npm):

`npm install lit-html`

Then [import into your JS file](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/getting-started#importing) like this:

`import {html, render} from './node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js';`

Then you call `html` and `render()` where required (https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/getting-started#rendering-a-template).

Answer (score 0):

Use this CDN in your index.html

```
<script>https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lit-html@0.13.0/lit-html.d.ts</script>
<script>https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lit-html@0.13.0/lit-html.d.ts.map</script>
<script>https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lit-html@0.13.0/lit-html.js.map</script>
```

Hope this will resolve uour problem